# Group API results in one DIV

Tags: javascript, google-api

I'm having a really hard time trying to edit the JS code/API (Google Feeds) to make it work in a responsive design.

Right now the results of the API is as followed :

```
<div class="gfg-subtitle"></div>
<div class="gfg-list"></div>
<div class="gfg-subtitle"></div>
<div class="gfg-list"></div>
...
```

I want it to be like that :

```
<div class="gfg-group">
    <div class="gfg-subtitle"></div>
    <div class="gfg-list"></div>
</div>
<div class="gfg-group">
    <div class="gfg-subtitle"></div>
    <div class="gfg-list"></div>
</div>
```

I tried this (but don't get any result) :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $("#contentfeed").append("<div class='gfg-grouped'></div>");     
$(".gfg-grouped").text($(".gfg-subtitle").text() + " " +$(".gfg-list").text()); });
```

Tried this as well (doesn't seem to work either) :

```
var groupDiv = document.createElement('div');
groupDiv.className = 'gfg-group';
groupDiv.appendChild(newTitle);
groupDiv.appendChild(newList);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/pnwm67q8/2/ :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the previous replies, I went on and solved it myself (took me way too long but that's how we all learn right? :) Leaving the solution here if that can help someone.

I added the following lines :

```
 var newGroup = this.createDiv_('gfg-grouped');
```

and

```
   if (!this.options.horizontal && this.options.stacked) {
        var newGroup = this.createDiv_('gfg-grouped');
        var newTitle = this.createDiv_('gfg-subtitle');
        nodes.root.appendChild(newGroup);
        newGroup.appendChild(newTitle);
        this.setTitle_(this.results[0].feed, newTitle);
```

and

```
  newGroup.appendChild(nodes.list);
```

See : http://jsfiddle.net/m5krqvbz/3/

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of logic going and I'm not familiar with the API on but you can group the entries like so:

```
    // group the Title and List
    var groupDiv = document.createElement('div');
    groupDiv.className = 'gfg-grouped';
    groupDiv.appendChild(newTitle);
    groupDiv.appendChild(newList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would get something like the following:

```
$intendedContainer = $("");
$(".gfg-subtitle").each(function(){
  var $list = $(this).next().detach();
  var $subitle = $(this).detach();

  var $groupItem = $("<div class='gfg-group'></div>");
  $groupItem.append($list).append($subtitle);
  $groupItem.insertBefore($subTitle);

  $intendedContainer.append($groupItem);
});
```

I didn't work through your entire code as it's quite huge, but this is the kind of logic you will need to implement.